# Add view to ViewGroup in dispatchDraw

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, viewgroup

I am trying to create a transperancy mask.
I have created a slidingScreen which extends `ViewGroup`.
in the constructor i add:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout roadMap = new LinearLayout(context);
    roadMap.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.addView(roadMap);
```

I then override the `onDispatchDraw()` method:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    Log.d("touchy touch", "dispatch draw called");

    canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LIGHT_BLUE));
    /* recreate the blue rectangle on the canvas */
    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0f, 0.0f);        // Top Left
    path.lineTo(0.0f, 800.0f);      // Bottom Left
    path.lineTo(0.0f, 800.0f );     // Bottom Right
    path.lineTo(this.x, 0.0f);      // Top Right
    path.close(); 
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);    
}
```

The result is I have a transparent mask which is equal to the path created. This is not the problem. Unfortunatley roadMap is never displayed.
I tried to override:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int count = this.getChildCount();
    Log.d("children please", "count: "+count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = this.getChildAt(i);
        child.layout(0, 0, child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());
        child.invalidate();
        child.bringToFront();
    }

}
```

Yet still the linearlayout i am trying to attach does not appear.

Comment: why do you addView in dispatchDraw??? this is the worst place to do it...

Comment: Where would you recommend? I am trying to create a Layout which is partially transparent. this should happen in response to to touch event.

Comment: the 1000 is caused because i add the view every ondraw.

Comment: Extend FrameLayout instead of ViewGroup and remove onLayout

Comment: Did it. didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to Extend FrameLayout.
Removed this line:

```
canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LIGHT_BLUE));
```

and then i was seeing the roadMap view!